# Remove rear rhomboid shaped window on 2002 Toyota Camry Station Wagon/Estate

Tags: toyota, repair, camry, window

I have rust around the rear rhomboid shaped window in my 2002 Toyota Camry station wagon/Estate. I would like to know how to remove the window so I can repair the rusted parts and then put it back in.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Could you post a picture?

Comment: The classic methods are either window rubber or glued in - check.